# Android - Data not downloading using mobile data/3G

Tags: java, android, http

I have an `android` app that the user can update by pressing an "UPDATE" button. This works perfect on **wifi**. However, on **mobile data**, it has a problem. The UPDATE process connects to my REST server and actually connects to 3 URLs for different data. On mobile data, the first and last URLs work fine, but the second one returns blank data. Like I said, on WIFI, all 3 URLs work perfect, but on 3G, they do not. It is always only the 2nd URL that is causing issues.

Here is my code. It is pretty standard:

```
//FIRST
URL url = new URL(Constants.firstURL); 
String line = null; 
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent(); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{ 
    sb.append(line); 
} 
firstRawData = sb.toString().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", ""); 
is.close(); 

//SECOND
url = new URL(Constants.secondURL); 
line = null; 
is = (InputStream) url.getContent(); 
sb = new StringBuilder(); 
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{ 
    sb.append(line); 
} 
secondRawData = sb.toString().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", ""); 
is.close();

//THIRD
url = new URL(Constants.thirdURL); 
line = null; 
is = (InputStream) url.getContent(); 
sb = new StringBuilder(); 
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{ 
    sb.append(line); 
} 
thirdRawData = sb.toString().replace(" ", "").replace("\n", ""); 
is.close();
```

I would appreciate any help with this as I have never encountered this issue before.

Thank you.

EDIT: There are no errors anywhere that I can see and I have the URL stuff in a `try/catch` which catch `MalformedURLException`, `IOException`, `NullPointerException` and no exceptions are thrown. Logcat doesnt tell me anything either.

Comment: might it be that mobile data is very slow and there's some constraint on url 2 regarding speed, timeout or something? do you see errors or warnings in logs (client / server)?

Comment: See edit. There is no errors or warnings anywhere, unfortunately. I am just using `Log.i()` to output the raw data, and it shows the second data as being blank. Thanks.

Comment: I would use a webdebugger like Charles to see the request and the response. If possible also look in the log of the server.

Comment: @eoinzy : Your question makes almost no sense with respect to the code you've shown. All you are showing is three identical blocks of code varying only by using a different URL and first/second/thirdRawData - how on earth is anybody supposed to explain to you why the second one always fails with mobile internet and not with wifi? You might as well simply posted a single block of code in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Ixx : My point is that we don't know what the URLs are but we're told the second one always fails on mobile internet. It's like asking the question "Why do URLs `http://.../1` and `http://.../3` work but `http://.../2` fails?". If, as shown in the code, all three downloads are done with identical code how is anybody supposed to give a definitive answer as to why the second always works with wifi but fails using mobile internet? We don't even know what the second URL refers to.

Comment: just take it as a verbose and proved way to express "identical" ;)

Comment: @Ixx : You still don't get my point. Forget my original comment about duplicate blocks of code and answer me this...Do YOU know what `Constants.secondURL` references? I certainly don't and it's effectively the only variable in the equation. If we don't know what it is, what data type (text/binary), what size file, what restrictions the OP's provider enforces, the original question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Squonk I stated that it was connecting to a `REST` server in the original question. The URLs are identical with the exception of the end part. When I browse to them in my `browser`, they are exactly as I should expect. I also stated that on `wifi` they work perfect. Therefore, it is reasonable to assume that the issue is 3G or mobile data related. So either the code is irrelevant and its just an Android quirk that I'm not aware of, or else the code is 100% relevant, for example, I've seen questions on here where the issue was simply a typo.

Comment: @eoinzy - are you staying that the three URLs are all on the same server, via the same domain name?  If so, have a look in the server logs.  Also consider adding some progress logging in each of the while loops.  If on the other hand the domain names are different, I'd consider the possibility of flaky DNS at the mobile provider.  Can you access the problem URL from the device's web browser?

Comment: Yes, same server, same domain name.works perfect on my phones browser. I will try search the server logs if I can. I am thinking maybe I should use a different URL object instead of reusing the same one, in case there's some weird garbage collection occurring.  Its just confusing that the issue is only on mobile data and not wifi.

Comment: Using multiple URL objects makes no difference. It has to be some sort of latency issue or some sort of threading issue. I can't figure it out at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I answered this myself after a while but forgot to reply.

The problem was the fact that I was calling this method from within a thread. The thread was going off to work, while the rest of the code was moving forward. By the time it moved forward, the 2nd URL just simply hadn't finished.

When I moved the call outside the thread and made it run sequentially, then everything was fine!

I was thinking I had to run any internet retrieval stuff in a thread but I think these calls are already in threads so it wasnt needed.